# Cannot create a MVC4 new project in VS web express 2012: invalid url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've created a new project then I saw this error:

```
the local iis server url is not valid URL that includes the protocol (http:// or https://) invalid url: the hostname could not be parsed
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you have iis installed?

Comment: @stevenackley I checked that after I saw that error, Yes I have IIS8 Express installed in my windows.

Comment: Go into Uninstall Programs --> Turn Windows features on --> Check off everything in IIS - WWW Services - Application Development Features also common HTTP features

Comment: @stevenackley I've done that but VS showed me the error again :(

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because i had an ASP.NET project called "A" in a VS solution called "S", then i deleted "A" to create a new ASP.NET project also called "A" with a diferent configuration. In this strange case, the IIS will fail to create a URI binded to a project with the same name as another.

The solution:

Go to "C:\Users\\Documents\IISExpress\config" and open the file "applicationhost.config", then delete all the "site" tags referencing your site, like

```
<site name="MyWeb" id="27">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Proyects\C#\MyWeb\MyWeb" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:12199:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

and also "location" tags like

```
<location path="MyWeb">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Save the .config file, reopen VS and try to create the project.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project -> Properties -> Click on the Web tab:

[image: properties]

If you want to use `IIS Express` you have to set it up here (see the example in the picture)

Please note that `IIS` and `IIS Express` are 2 different applications (http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview).